# estimateEffect on STM for prevalence of topics over time

Tags: r, nlp, topic-modeling, quanteda

I have a table with the columns (varibles): doc_id, day, month, year, speaker, text.
I use the stm and quanteda package to find an optimal K and I get the topics.
Now I want to show which topic was at what time - prevalence over time. But I don't get it.
I created a stm for the topics with:

```
dfm2stm <- convert(fed_speeches.dfm.trim, to = "stm")
stm.modell <- stm(dfm2stm$documents, dfm2stm$vocab, K, data = 
dfm2stm$meta, init.type = "Spectral")
as.data.frame(t(labelTopics(stm.modell, n= 10)$prob))
```

and the topics were created. But the combination of the topics and time (with using estimateEffects) it doesn't work. The code:

```
stm.modell.labels <- labelTopics(stm.modell, 1:K) 
dfm2stm$meta$Year <- as.numeric(dfm2stm$meta$Year)
stm.modell.effect <- estimateEffect(1:K ~ topic + s(Year), stm.modell,
dfm2stm$meta)
```

I think I need a variable to combine this with the time but using topic leads to an error like object not found.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am not 100% I got it. you have a set of documents per each year right (or just one document per year)? Then for each year you want the most important topic (i.e.  the one with highest probability)? in that case you might want to use the function which.max()

Comment: I have 188 documents for 2 years and the optimal K (number of topics) is 30 (estimation with searchK). I want to know with a curve when was which topic in this 2 years relevant with the plot:

Comment: plot(modell.stm.effekt, "year", method = "continuous", topics = i, main = paste0(modell.stm.labels$prob[i,1:3], collapse = ", "), ylab = "", printlegend = F)